# CORS block for api.mainnet-beta.solana.com

Tags: rpc, jsonrpc-api

Is there a policy for cross-origin requests to `api.mainnet-beta.solana.com`?

Suddenly my domain is being rejected (which ends in `.finance`).

What is the `strict-origin-when-cross-origin` policy?

The preflight request is receiving a 403.

Comment: This is a bug, and it's being fixed. Thanks for raising this! Feel free to delete this question once things start working for you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it refers to a transient issue that's being fixed.